# Java - File not found with ö or ü in UNC

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working with [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to handle some PDF files on an external storage. I was loading them in and noticed in my logs I got some `File NotFoundExceptions`. I was looking in the Exception and noticed a weird sign (a black square with a `?` inside in = �) the [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

This is how I make my files. I get the String from a buffered reader if that makes a difference.

```
    File myPathFile
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(myPathFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)
    String o = br.readLine();
    File f = new File(o)
```

I thought it was the same as:

```
     File f = new File("\\test\ö\myFile.pdf"); //When the UNC looks like this it won't work. (the ö is �)
     File f2 = new File("\\test\myFile.pdf");   //This works
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? It shouldn't even compile... `\m` is not a valid escape. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Comment: That's not a URL, that a UNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not a URL, it is a UNC.

Then, it's not a correct UNC, because you are forgetting some pretty important parts.

```
\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource
```

Where the grouping is

```
[\\] flag to suggest it's a UNC
[ComputerName] The name of the remote computer
[\] separator character
[SharedFolder] The shared folder name
[\Resource] The path name of the remote file
```

Finally, you are not escaping your special characters within the string correctly, so you are probably not even getting off of your machine, much less getting to where you want.

To type the `\` in Java, you need to know that `\` is used for *special* characters like null, backspace, etc.  So to get a single, normal `\` you must type `\\`.  That would make your first example.

On non-Microsoft systems, keep in mind that the remote path name probably uses `/` instead of `\`, and that `/` is not an escape character, so there is no need to type it twice.

```
 File f = new File("\\\\test\\ö\\myFile.pdf");
```

Which won't work because you don't have a shared folder named `ö`

and your second example

```
 File f2 = new File("\\\\test\\myFile.pdf");
```

Your second example wouldn't work, because it lacks a resource to be opened.

Assuming you didn't want to walk off of your machine, you are missing parts of a local file name.  On windows a full path includes the "volume name" which is typically `C:` or something similar.

```
 File f = new File("c:\\test\\myFile.pdf");
```

Sometimes people omit the volume name, in which case you rely upon the operating system's good graces to attempt to find the file for you.  Generally speaking, it's not a great idea.

```
 File f = new File("\\test\\myFile.pdf");
```

But even though this looks similar to your second example, it contains an extra forward slash to escape the forward slash.  While your actual example doesn't.

Comment: Some other combinations might work, but only because your operating system is trying to "help you out".  They are not valid names, but Microsoft Windows has a history that includes _sometimes_ allowing you to do invalid things because allowing invalid things is considered a key point of usability in Microsoft's history.

Comment: It's working fine for 100000 other files so I had no idea I had to change it. I think the fileshare is from unix server. The unc's seem to mix like this: \\test\myFolder/myfile.pdf

Comment: I updated the answer to better cover multi-platform issues.  Thanks for the pointer.